# raised BadValueError(Entity has uninitialized properties: created_by)

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, web-applications, google-cloud-datastore, webapp2

i am getting 500 error. i checked the logs on google app engine. And i find out it was due to *raised BadValueError(Entity has uninitialized properties: created_by)*

there is a screen shot of the logs. do have a check below. 
[image]

the model in which we use to create the datastore is this .

```
class YoProject(BaseNDBExpando):
project_name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
***created_by = ndb.KeyProperty(required=True)***
created_by_name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True, indexed=False)
client_name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
client_spoc_name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True, indexed=False)
client_spoc_email = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
type_ = ndb.StringProperty(required=True, choices=["tm", "pa"])
description = ndb.TextProperty(indexed=False)
hidden = ndb.BooleanProperty(required=True, default=False)
```

it was running fine. but when i try to introduce a class property in it.i start getting this error and also on GAE Datastore dashboard there are two same property of different datatypes i don,t how to handle this situation. need guidance and help from senior developers.

[image]

Comment: @DanCornilescu i need you help on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in local environment, I would suggest you to delete/flush all entities of this model.

Then try to reproduce it using another word than `classes` as property name.

Comment: classes is  not issue  but the Bad Value Error(Entity has uninitialized properties: created_by) the app is still runs but i have to refresh the page to move forward in app.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* I saw this error as well in my early GAE days, when I was modifying the entity models all the time, I'm much more reluctant to do it nowadays as I know that such changes need extra care and almost always a migration strategy.

I got it after I added the `required=True` option to a model's property. The option causes an error if you're trying to `put` am entity without that property set, obviously. But it also causes an error when trying to get an entity `put` in the datastore without the property being set, before the option was enabled in the model. This is what I suspect may be happening. Note that this check is `ndb`-specific, so it will affect your app code, but not the console viewer or apps using other client libraries.

Look at all entities of that kind in the [Entity menu](https://console.cloud.google.com/datastore/entities/query), checking which don't have the property set.

Try enabling debugging for your app (by passing `debug=True` in your app's `webapp2.WSGIApplication()` call), which *should* show a traceback attached to the respective request log. It would be helpful to figure out where exactly is the error encountered.

The duplicates you highlighted in the Dashboard image may be red herrings - I see similar ones on my apps as well, with no ill effects (or at least none that I noticed).

I'm not sure if some of them aren't side effects of the various changes I did in time to the entity models, in particular flipping the `indexed` setting for some properties.

But I'm almost certain the String/Text ones are simply caused by the datastore [Text string](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#text_string) properties being indexed only if the value has less than 1500 bytes (i.e what's considered as different property types in `ndb` - `TextProperty` and `StringProperty`).

Also note the `0B` indexes are normal for properties being not indexed, see for example your `description` property.